# Python dataframe sume iterative

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe like this:

```
t; value
5; 10   
4; 0
3; 2
2; 0
1; 1
```

What I want is to sum iterative over the columns in row "values" so that I get this:

```
t; value; sum
5; 10;    13
4; 0;     3
3; 2;     3
2; 0;     1
1; 1;     1
```

How I can do this in python with dataframe?

t = time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `cumsum` that calculates the cumulative sum from the top to the bottom. Reverse the dataframe, then calculate the sum:

```
df['sum'] = df.loc[::-1, 'value'].cumsum()
#   t   value  sum
#0  5      10   13
#1  4       0    3
#2  3       2    3
#3  2       0    1
#4  1       1    1
```

Comment: You do not need second [::-1] `df['sum'] = df.loc[::-1, 'value'].cumsum()`

Comment: Can you additionally tell me how I dividend this new colum for each t?

So taht i get another row with: 13/5; 3/4; 3/3; 1;2; 1/1

Comment: df.loc[::-1, 'value'].cumsum()/df.t @Pablo

Comment: Just divide the columns: `df['sum']/df['t']`,

Comment: Thank you! I had the row t as the index. Thats why it was not working. Thanks for everything!